# error defining operator == and operator > using binary search tree

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i am working on a program that reads in a text file that the user inputs, creates a text file that the user inputs, names the text file that the user wants, and then sorts the text file sorting words above the user entered in threshold and displays the words and how many times it was found to the output file the user specify's. i have most of the code finished but im getting a compiler error heres the sample output, error and code

sample output

Enter name of input command file; press return.
history.in
Enter name of output file; press return.
history.out
Enter name of test run; press return.
sample
Enter the minimum size word to be considered.
5
Sample results (found in user specified output file):
sample
abacus 4
abstract 1
adding 1
addition 2
advances 1
after 3

where the word is the word found in the text file, and the number next to it is how many times it was found.

The compiler errors are:

```
C:\Users\kevin jack\Desktop\prog-4>g++ -o try main.cpp
main.cpp:(.text+0x329) undefined reference to `StrType::PrintToFile(bool, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
:main.cpp:(.text+0x608): undefined reference to `StrType::GetStringFile(bool, InType, std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x639): undefined reference to `StrType::LenghtIs()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x6d8): undefined reference to `StrType::GetStringFile(bool, InType, std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

i have no idea what this means if anyone knows please inform me here is my code

main.cpp

```
//main.cpp
#include <fstream>
#include "StrType.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct WordType
{
       public:
              StrType word;       
              int count;


};


struct TreeNode
{
       WordType info;
       TreeNode* left;
       TreeNode* right;

};

class ListType
{
      public:
             ListType();
             void InsertOrIncrement (StrType string);
             void Print(std::ofstream&) const;
      private:
              TreeNode* root;
};


ListType::ListType()
{
     root=NULL;
}

void Process(TreeNode*& tree, StrType s)
{

     if(tree == NULL)
     {
         tree = new TreeNode;
         tree->info.word = s;
         tree->info.count = 1;
         tree->left = NULL;
         tree->right = NULL;
     }

     else if (tree->info.word == s)
         tree->info.count++;
     else if (s < tree->info.word)
         Process(tree->left, s);
     else 
         Process(tree->right, s);
}

void ListType::InsertOrIncrement(StrType s)
{
     Process(root, s);
}

void Print (TreeNode* tree, std::ofstream& outFile)
 {

      if (tree!= NULL)
      {
          Print(tree->left, outFile);
          tree->info.word.PrintToFile(true, outFile);
          outFile <<" "<< tree->info.count;
          Print(tree->right, outFile);
      }
 }

 void ListType::Print(std::ofstream& outFile) const
 {
      ::Print(root, outFile);
 }


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    ListType list;
    string inFileName;
    string outFileName;
    string outputLabel;
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    StrType string;
    int minimumLenght;

    cout<<"enter in imput file name."<<endl;
    cin>>inFileName;
    inFile.open(inFileName.c_str());

    cout<<"enter name of output file."<<endl;
    cin>>outFileName;
    outFile.open(outFileName.c_str());

    cout<<"enter name of test run."<<endl;
    cin>>outputLabel;
    outFile<< outputLabel << endl;

    cout<<"enter the min word size."<<endl;
    cin>>minimumLenght;

    string.GetStringFile(true, ALPHA_NUM, inFile);
    while(inFile)
    {

         if(string.LenghtIs() >= minimumLenght)
            list.InsertOrIncrement(string);
         string.GetStringFile(true, ALPHA_NUM, inFile);
    }

    list.Print(outFile);
    outFile.close();
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

StrType.h

```
//StrType.h
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

const int MAX_CHARS=100;
enum InType{ALPHA_NUM, ALPHA, NON_WHITE, NOT_NEW};

class StrType
{
      public:
             void MakeEmpty();
            void GetString(bool skip, InType charsAllowed);
             void GetStringFile(bool skip, InType charsAllowed,
                std::ifstream& inFile);
             void PrintToScreen(bool newLine);
             void PrintToFile(bool newLine, std::ofstream& outFile);
             int LenghtIs();
             void CopyString(StrType& newString);
              bool operator==(const StrType& other) const;  
              bool operator<(const StrType& other) const;




      private:
              char letters[MAX_CHARS + 1];

};
bool StrType::operator==(const StrType& other) const  
{  
    return (strcmp(letters, other.letters) == 0);  
}  

bool StrType::operator<(const StrType& other) const  
{  
    return (strcmp(letters, other.letters) < 0);  
}  

void StrType::MakeEmpty()
{
     letters[0] ='\0';
}
```

what i was trying to overload the == and > operator. i am stating it in class StrType and defining it just below it but im not sure if im defining it correctly or even in the right spot! any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: have you defined all member functions of `class StrType`? Your code shows that you have defined only those operators and `StrType::MakeEmpty()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notMine.cpp

```
 //StrType.h
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

const int MAX_CHARS=100;
enum InType{ALPHA_NUM, ALPHA, NON_WHITE, NOT_NEW};

class StrType
{
      public:
             void MakeEmpty();
            void GetString(bool skip, InType charsAllowed)
            {
            }
            void GetStringFile(bool skip, InType charsAllowed, std::ifstream& inFile)
            {
            }
            void PrintToScreen(bool newLine)
            {
            }
            void PrintToFile(bool newLine, std::ofstream& outFile)
            {
            }
            int LenghtIs()
            {
                     return 0; 
            }
            void CopyString(StrType& newString)
            {
            }
            bool operator==(const StrType& other) const
            {  
                     return (strcmp(letters, other.letters) == 0);  
            }  
            bool operator<(const StrType& other) const
            {  
                    return (strcmp(letters, other.letters) < 0);  
            }  




      private:
              char letters[MAX_CHARS + 1];

};


void StrType::MakeEmpty()
{
     letters[0] ='\0';
}
```

myOwnSomething.h

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <fstream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "myOwnSomething.h" 
using namespace std;

struct WordType
{
       public:
       StrType word;       
       int count;


};


struct TreeNode
{
       WordType info;
       TreeNode* left;
       TreeNode* right;

};

class ListType
{
      public:
             ListType();
             void InsertOrIncrement (StrType string);
             void Print(std::ofstream&) const;
      private:
              TreeNode* root;
};


ListType::ListType()
{
     root=NULL;
}

void Process(TreeNode*& tree, StrType s)
{

     if(tree == NULL)
     {
         tree = new TreeNode;
         tree->info.word = s;
         tree->info.count = 1;
         tree->left = NULL;
         tree->right = NULL;
     }

     else if (tree->info.word == s)
         tree->info.count++;
     else if (s < tree->info.word)
         Process(tree->left, s);
     else 
         Process(tree->right, s);
}

void ListType::InsertOrIncrement(StrType s)
{
     Process(root, s);
}

void Print (TreeNode* tree, std::ofstream& outFile)
 {

      if (tree!= NULL)
      {
          Print(tree->left, outFile);
          tree->info.word.PrintToFile(true, outFile);
          outFile <<" "<< tree->info.count;
          Print(tree->right, outFile);
      }
 }

 void ListType::Print(std::ofstream& outFile) const
 {
      ::Print(root, outFile);
 }


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    ListType list;
    string inFileName;
    string outFileName;
    string outputLabel;
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    StrType string;
    int minimumLenght;

    cout<<"enter in imput file name."<<endl;
    cin>>inFileName;
    inFile.open(inFileName.c_str());

    cout<<"enter name of output file."<<endl;
    cin>>outFileName;
    outFile.open(outFileName.c_str());

    cout<<"enter name of test run."<<endl;
    cin>>outputLabel;
    outFile<< outputLabel << endl;

    cout<<"enter the min word size."<<endl;
    cin>>minimumLenght;

    string.GetStringFile(true, ALPHA_NUM, inFile);
    while(inFile)
    {

         if(string.LenghtIs() >= minimumLenght)
            list.InsertOrIncrement(string);
         string.GetStringFile(true, ALPHA_NUM, inFile);
    }

    list.Print(outFile);
    outFile.close();
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to define all the member functions. int LenghtIs(); also needs to return an int. The edited version of your code (above) works. Cheers

Comment: ok so using that it compiles but doesnt output to a folder. and where should i put the commented out bool StrType stuff at? thank you for the help as well

Comment: it outputs to a text file just fine, i tested it with an output file called blahOUT.txt. The stuff that is commented out is added within your class.... so u can delete the commented code out.. i've updated it with it deleted

Comment: hmm... interesting after i enter in the min word i just a blinking under bar and does nothing i have to control c to get the cmd abort the operation

Comment: hmm, i'm not sure why you are experiencing this issue. I've run your program several times and it works fine. I've pasted the code of your "main.cpp" file above as well...i re-named the files as follows: "notMine.cpp" was ur main.cpp your "strType.h" i re-named to "myownSomething.h"

Comment: i get that strcmp has not been declared in the scope. it would be in the bool operators in the myOwnSomething.h it seems to compile fine on my computer but hangs after you hit enter on the min word cout and it doesnt compile on my schools lab computer... interesting

Comment: Hmm, i'm not actually sure why that's happening in your code to be honest. Sorry =/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile and check your code, you should define all member functions of all classes at least as (nearly) empty functions.

```
void StrType::GetString(bool skip, InType charsAllowed)  
{
    // empty function, you will write your code heree later  
}  
// ...
```

Don't forget about return-values for non-void functions